# json response validation in java (Assertion)

Tags: java, rest, testing, rest-assured

I am successfully parsing JSON in body and getting response. But I want to know how to validate the response. Right now as part of validation i am just validating the status code.

```
protected ResponseSpecification somefunction() {
        ResponseBuilder builder = new ResponseBuilder();
        builder.expectContentType(ContentType.JSON).

                expectStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK_200);

        return builder.build();
    }
```

But my json response looks something like this:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "numSucceeded": 1
}
```

Thus How to validate message as numSucceeded is 1 in java?

Answer (score 0):

Your can do it as assertion for `ValidatableResponse`:

```
given().
when().
    get("http://example.com/")
then().
    assertThat().
    body("numSucceeded", equalTo(1));
```

or using builder:

```
builder.expectBody("numSucceeded", equalTo(1));
```

Any way these cases are described in rest-assured [documentation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage).